# Looping over array of objects

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jquery-ui

I'm working on an asp.net app that is utilizing a lot of jQuery UI controls particularly the datepicker.

In my web service I am making a call to the database and retrieving a list of objects and then passing them back to my javascript where I parse them out into an array containing 1 or more objects that look like this:

[image: javascript object]

I need to include some kind of logic in which I can loop through this array of objects and check to see if a javascript Date falls in between the EndDate and StartDate properties of the object so that I can apply a css style for the DatePicker. First question, is there a way to convert the EndDate/StartDate property from this format to a valid javascript Date?
And if so how can I iterate over the array and apply the logic to see if the date falls inside the range?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I noticed the image here is kind of hard to see you can more clearly read the properties here:

[image link](https://postimg.cc/fVY8Zfhx)

As requested here is some example code:

```
function createDateRangesForCalendar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Services/BookingService.asmx/GetCalendarDateRanges",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            dateRanges = $.parseJSON(response.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}

function markInvalidDates(date) {

    var isHoliday = false;
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

    isHoliday = checkIsHoliday(date);

    if ($.inArray(dmy, invalidDays) == -1) {

        for (var i = 0; i < dateRanges.length; i++) {
            // if date falls in between start and end date of object[i] return something like: return [true, "holiday", "Holiday Rates Apply - Minimum 14 days"];
            // else loop through to the next object and try there
            } 

        if (isHoliday == true) {
            return [true, "holiday", "Holiday Rates Apply - Minimum 14 days"];
        } else {
            return [true, ""];
        }
    } else {
        return [false, "unavailable", "Unavailable"];
    }
}
```

Comment: the image would be better if zoomed somewhat

Comment: SO you have a start and an end date, what are you comparing them against?

Comment: I included a link to a readable version of the image. And what code would you like to see? I can show you the ajax call that receives the json string from my webservice but I haven't done anything with it yet besides parsing it to an array of objects which look like the one in the image.

Comment: I have another date. I want to see if that date falls in between the startdate and endate of any of the objects in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question, is there a way to convert the EndDate/StartDate property from this format to a valid javascript Date?**

The format seems to be this: `/Date(MILLISECONDS)/`. A valid JS date object can be obtained like this: `new Date(s.match(/Date\((\d+)/)[1])`.

**And if so how can I iterate over the array and apply the logic to see if the date falls inside the range?**

```
var re = /Date\((\d+)/;
for(var i in arr) {
    var start = new Date(arr[i].startDate.match(re)[1]),
        end = new Date(arr[i].endDate.match(re)[1]);
    if(myDate < end && myDate > start)
        // do something.
}
```

The above seems to answer your question, the way I understand it.

Comment: This looks really promising. I have to leave school at the moment but I will try it as soon as I get home and let you know if it worked out.

Comment: Hey I just tried your method and I am getting invalid date on both start and end, possibly because the regex isn't stripping off all unnecessary characters? I'll do some investigating and see if I can figure it out. Sorry my js is weak I'm sure its something really simple. Other than that everything looks like its in order.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I threw in some breakpoints and your regex is definitely properly parsing out only the millisecond value but I am still getting an invalid date when I call new Date() on it.

Comment: I couldn't get the Date constructor to work using the number of milliseconds so I ended up making a partial class to extend the properties of the entity object to include valid date strings for the start and end date. After that everything works like a charm! Thanks so much for the help everyone! I will post a link to the site to show you what this helped me to accomplish once I get it up on FTP.

Comment: sorry, couldn't reply to any of your questions. It was night here, and I could log in only now, once I have access to internet...happy to help, always!

Answer (score 2):

StartDate and EndDate seem like valid JSON to me, except for the slashes at end and beginning. Otherwise, a simple eval of the value should produce a JS Date Object on which you can operate.

For your second point, what keeps you from classic looping over the array ? Some code would be much more useful to say more.

Comment: yes it is, mostly, but not for controlled environments. Now, I know this isn't a controlled environment, but just saying.

Comment: @Claude : Indeed. Let's say JSON.parse()

Comment: Alright that answers one of my questions I guess, I needed to know if the format for start and end date represented valid javascript dates. So you're saying if I strip off the slashes I can just call new Date with the value in brackets? And if that works I probably shouldn't have much trouble writing a classic loop myself. I have a strong .NET programming background but am still trying to understand the ins and outs of javascript and JSON as I only started recently using them

Comment: Look over here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks for the link to the javascript reference I didn't even know about this... Bookmarked for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Just return your start and end dates as numerics, without the \Date()\ wrappers.

In your loop, create a JavaScript date from your target date, i.e. `new Date(1334548800000)` then use simple comparisons between your target date and those start and end dates.

While you can loop with `$.each(yourArray, function(id,item){ date comparison logic here });` I recommend you look into the Underscore library for a decent set of utilities to manipulate JS objects.

Comment: If avoidable I'd prefer not to do this as I am simply using a javascript serializer in my C# web method to package up the list of objects and I would have to write a new class to handle what you're talking about. I will definitely look into underscore though.